# TF 1.0.10: When removing count from module, plan wants to destroy then re-create everything

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I started a TF project on `v0.14.8` and at the time used `count` to select a module like so:

```
module "moduleA" { 
  source                         = "./moduleA"
  count                          = var.aws_env == "moduleA" ? 1 : 0
  aws_env                        = var.aws_env
  aws_security_group_id          = var.aws_security_group_id
  aws_subnet_1                   = var.aws_subnet_1
}

module "moduleB" {
  source                         = "./moduleB"
  count                          = var.aws_env == "moduleB" ? 1 : 0
  aws_env                        = var.aws_env
  aws_security_group_id          = var.aws_security_group_id
  aws_subnet_1                   = var.aws_subnet_1
}
```

When I would run `terraform plan/apply`, I would have the `aws_env` set to `moduleA` or `moduleB` to select that module.

I have since updated to `v1.0.10` successfully and am looking to get rid of the `count` argument because of it's inherent blockers with [Providers within Modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html). My latest main.tf looks like so:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.10"
  backend "s3" {
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

module "moduleA" { 
  source                         = "./moduleA"  
  aws_env                        = var.aws_env
  aws_security_group_id          = var.aws_security_group_id
  aws_subnet_1                   = var.aws_subnet_1
}

module "moduleB" {
  source                         = "./moduleB"
  aws_env                        = var.aws_env
  aws_security_group_id          = var.aws_security_group_id
  aws_subnet_1                   = var.aws_subnet_1
}

variable "aws_env" {}
variable "aws_security_group_id" {}
variable "aws_subnet_1" {}
```

This works great conceptually as I plan/apply the TF like so (`{TF_ACTION}` is set to `plan` or `apply`):

`terraform ${TF_ACTION} -target=module.${AWS_ENV} -input=false` with `{AWS_ENV}` set to `moduleA` or `moduleB`.

The problem I'm facing is that once `count` has been removed, on a TF `plan` - TF wants to destroy and re-create all 155+ of my AWS resources - including KMS keys which are currently encrypting data.

##### How can I avoid TF wanting to destroy then re-create everything while removing `count`?

Comment: There are several red flags here that have been and will cause problems for you, but to answer your question directly: at this point you would probably need to do a global replacement in your state file. Please share a relevant snippet of the state for a resource so we can provide an answer.

Comment: [State gist](https://gist.github.com/mcspadden-sd/e495cbc1f3b53bc4b878030388d8a2b6) - thanks for your help. Could you mention the problems you see? If I have to break some things now it would be better than doing it in 2 years with more resources built lol

Comment: I added the following to the KMS key, which is really the only resource we care about not destroying: 
`resource "aws_kms_key" "moduleB_client_kms_key" {
  description             = "ModuleB KMS key for ${var.client_code}"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }`

Comment: Getting this error now:
`Resource module.moduleB[0].module.moduleB_client_name.aws_kms_key.moduleb_client_kms_key has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the plan calls for this resource to be destroyed. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or reduce the scope of the plan using the -target flag.`

Hence the count [0] that's present on the plan still